# Продолжить работу с того места, где остановился скрипт

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом правильно реализовать следующий момент:
Есть скрипт, который перебирает файлы и копирует их в папку. Трешхолд стоит на размере файлов 1ТБ, т.е. как только скрипт нашел и скопировал 1ТБ файлов, он останавливается, дальше отрабатывают другие скрипты, которые работают с этими файлами.
Вопрос, как реализовать некий чекпоинт, который при следующем запуске скрипта не будет обрабатывать уже обработанные файлы а продолжит с того места, где он остановился?
Пример на маленьких числах
0-9
10-20
21-30 ...

Answer (score 0):

Почему нельзя просто записывать последний обработанный файл в некий документ и уже оттуда брать информацию, или же создать текстовик с названиями всех файлов и обработанные удалять от туда.

Comment: Можно, и как вариант

Comment: Просто хотел узнать, как пойди к этому вопросу более грамотно

Answer (score 0):

1. То что копируется в папку можно где-то хранить и проверять название файла.
2. Если у файлов структурированное именование, то спасёт сохранение только последнего файла и функция умеющая понять свежий файл ДО или ПОСЛЕ последнего файла.
3. Можно ещё заморочиться с датой файла, если файлы создаются(редактируются, копируются,...) по времени и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, проще всего, воспользоваться оператором **yield** ?

*Yield — это ключевое слово в Python, которое используется для возврата из функции с сохранением состояния ее локальных переменных, и при повторном вызове такой функции выполнение продолжается с оператора yield, на котором ее работа была прервана.*